# Should Flask blueprint names be unique?

Tags: flask

I have several packages in my Flask project. Each package contains several [blueprints](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/blueprints/). Now can I have a blueprint with the same name as for example `bp` in multiple packages?

Answer (score 0):

No, the blueprint names *must* be unique.

```
>>> from flask import Flask, Blueprint
>>> app = Flask("app")
>>> blueprint = Blueprint("hello", "/hello")
>>> blueprint2 = Blueprint("hello", "/hello2")
>>> app.register_blueprint(blueprint)
>>> app.register_blueprint(blueprint2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/erip/tmp/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/scaffold.py", line 50, in wrapper_func
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/erip/tmp/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1296, in register_blueprint
    blueprint.register(self, options)
  File "/Users/erip/tmp/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/blueprints.py", line 384, in register
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: The name 'hello' is already registered for a different blueprint. Use 'name=' to provide a unique name.
>>> app.register_blueprint(blueprint, name="bp1")
>>> app.register_blueprint(blueprint2, name="bp2")
>>> app.blueprints
{'hello': <Blueprint 'hello'>, 'bp1': <Blueprint 'hello'>, 'bp2': <Blueprint 'hello'>}
```

Comment: But they are not in different packages. I mean is there any way to distinguish them by their package name?

Comment: You can use `__name__` which is the most typical way to name blueprints (and flask apps themselves).